# How to get the DataType property of a node in OPC.UA

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

I'm new in Opc.Ua and I want to list all nodes from a server. Now I can get the `ReferenceDescription` object of all nodes with `DisplayName` and so on except `DataType`. I have tried to call `session.NodeCache.Find` with a parameter of `TypeDefinition`, `TypeId` and `ReferenceTypeId` but none of them could get the correct DataType. So how can I get the `DataType` according a `ReferenceDescription` object and a `Session` object?

Answer (score 2):

You should call the Read service to read the `DataType` attribute. You might also want to read the `ValueRank` and `ArrayDimensions` attributes.